# How can I put text next to a SVG Icon with the same padding on all line breaks?

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to place the Text next to the Icon, but how can I do this?
If I apply a padding to it it just works on the first line of the text.

**Used Code:**

```
<div style="font-weight:400;font-size:14.5px;color:#212121">
<span class="uk-margin-small-right-info uk-icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 256" width="25" height="25" style="margin-top:-2px"><g><path d="M128 19.4C68 19.4 19.4 68 19.4 128S68 236.6 128 236.6 236.6 188 236.6 128 188 19.4 128 19.4zm0 228.6C61.7 248 8 194.3 8 128S61.7 8 128 8s120 53.7 120 120-53.7 120-120 120z"/><path d="M122.3 99.4h11.4v85.7h-11.4zM122.3 73.7h11.4V88h-11.4z"/></g></svg></span>Lorem rhoncus adipiscing ridiculus a lundium in et, dolor, pulvinar pid! Mauris enim nec pulvinar, magnis quis mid magna pellentesque? A etiam, aliquet rhoncus, magna lacus elementum</div>
```

**How it should look like:**
[image]

**How it looks like atm:**
[image]

The CSS Used is this:

```
.uk-margin-small-right-info {
  margin-right: 10px !important;
  display: inline-block
}
```

Comment: Different ways, simplest one is to make `inline-block` both `<svg>` and the `<span>` of the text you want to show next to it.

Comment: Make it float... And bigger, it's way too small to span on 3 lines as it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/webdsdyL/. The idea is to use `float:left` and set width on your text element.